# Android: display menu across several activities

Tags: android, menu, menuitem

I have several activities in my app. I want my activities to have the same menuitem, except one. I was wondering if there is an easy way to put the menuitem in all selected activities instead of copying and pasting the menuitem for each single activity? Basically I want to share the menuitem with selected activities.

Thanks,

Answer (score 10, accepted):

create a class (say class A) which extends activity and then create all your other activities by extending this class. Now in A keep the common menu items stored in a vector and any specific menu action can be added for any particular activity. This way you avoid the trouble of copying and pasting the menu items in every activity

Comment: Thanks for the solution! It did work, but not all my classes were extending Activity, some were extending ListActivity and had dependencies on that class directly, so I am not sure if extending class A in this case would work out.

Comment: why not use a listview instead of a listactivity. listview will provide everything listactivity provides. Just create listview as a member variable of your activity and use it

Answer (score 1):

This is the general idea behind MVC - to be able to show different Views (Activities) with same model(menu data).

If you load these menus dynamically - make a Singleton class with the menu data and get it from it.

If these menus are already defined in xxx.xml - you must create new menu.xml (for example) and extract the menu description there. Then include it in all activity layouts which need that menu.

You can also always dynamicaly inflate that menu.xml.